# Mathematics related anagrams

Tags: word, knowledge, anagram

Which two mathematics related words are anagrams of **ALERTING** and **ALTERING** and **RELATING**?

Comment: "Altering" and "relating" are also related to mathematics (through graph theory, for instance).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Integral and Triangle: A long sum, and a common shape.

Comment: +1 I never knew that these two were anagrams...now maybe I am 1 step ahead of my friends... :D